# ElasticSearch - see NEW unique term values as a sub-aggregation for date histograms

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch date histogram aggregation where I'd like to see NEW unique terms that were added for a given date datapoint. I've read about the cumulative cardinality aggregation that gets you a count of new unique values, but is there a way to return a list of buckets of new term values that did not exist in previous data points?